# Why is the pow function return 0 if y exceeds 64?

Tags: go

Why is the result of pow zero if y is greater than 64?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func pow(x uint64, y uint64) uint64 {
    if y > 64 {
        return 0
    }
    var result uint64 = 1
    var counter uint64
    var previous uint64
    for y > 0 {
        previous = result
        result = result * x
        y = y - 1
        counter++
        if result == 0 {
            return previous
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    result1 := pow(2, 64)
    fmt.Println(result1)
    result2 := pow(2, 32)
    fmt.Println(result2)
    result3 := pow(2, 3)
    fmt.Println(result3)
}
```

I just realized that it is because it is in base 2. What can you say about this? (I am still new to programming and with golang.)

Comment: `2^64` does not fit into `uint64`. (has nothing to do with base 2, actually, that would happen with fixed size integers in any base, unless you mean the fact that it becomes a perfect 0, rather than "random overflow").

Comment: Your code has a bug. Check my answer.

Comment: You got correct answers from both Thilo and khrm. But your code does not even get there - there is a condition ` if y > 64 return 0`. That's why your implementation returns 0 if y > 64...

Comment: @MirekE I mention that. That condition should be 63 if what he is trying to do is print power of 2. But I thought he is asking why that function should return 0 in case y > 64.

Comment: `pow` looks like it should compute x^y (mod 2^64), but it has weird edge cases (like returning 0 when y > 64, and returning "previous" when result is 0). So I think the correct answer to the question is either that you need to spell out what the function is supposed to do, or that it's just buggy and you can't read meaning into the mistakes.

Comment: pow should compute x^y. I am  just trying to trap cases where it returns 0 when it maxes out uint64. I am also at lost when I am expecting a max number of 18446744073709551615.

Comment: @Efox If you want to detect overflow, and send 0 in those cases then use snippet that I have written. I am assuming you want to return 0 where there's overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pow shouldn't be based on what is y.  It would be less for bigger number.

Use this:

`

```
// Assuming that b will never be 0
func mult(a, b uint64) (uint64, bool) {
    result := a * b
    return result, (result/b == a)
}

func pow(x uint64, y uint64) uint64 {
if y == 0 {
    return 1
}
if x == 0 {
    return 0
}
var result uint64 = 1
var counter uint64
var previous uint64
var ok bool
for y > 0 {
    previous = result
    result, ok = mult(result, x)
    if !ok {
        return 0
    }

    y = y - 1
    counter++
    if result == 0 {
        return previous
    }
}
    return result
}
```

Old answer before clarification:

Actually it should be 63. It is because uint64 can have at max can have largest number as 2 ^ (64) -1 (2 raise to the power 64 minux 1). 
So maximum number that can be generated for 2 power is 2 ^ 63.

You can confirm that by running your code. It would give you same result as for all number greater that 63 if you remove the restriction of y > 64 . (9223372036854775808 or 2^63). That restriction should be y > 63.